# Pick elements in pd.DataFrame with index and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` like

```
   B1 B2 B3
A1  0  1  2
A2  3  4  5
```

Also, `index=pd.Index(['A2', 'A1'])`, and `columns=pd.Index(['B2', 'B3'])`. What I want to get is `[4, 2]`, that is, elements in A2-B2 and A1-B3, respectively.

Is there a clever built-in operation to perform this in pandas?

I searched with different expressions for a while but no clue. There could be duplicate questions, sorry for that case. Thank you for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for positions by values of `index, columns` so possible filter in numpy indexing (only convert values of df to numpy array):

```
index=pd.Index(['A2', 'A1'])
columns=pd.Index(['B2', 'B3'])
i = df.index.get_indexer(index)
c = df.columns.get_indexer(columns)

L = df.to_numpy()[i, c].tolist()
print (L)
[4, 2]
```

Or reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
L = df.stack().loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(index, columns))].tolist()
print (L)
[4, 2]
```

If only few values is possible use list comprehension with `zip` and [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
L = [df.at[i, c] for i, c in zip(index, columns)]
print (L)
[4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to zip the index and columns (same idea as @Jezrael); however, you could just pass the unpacked values to loc (internally , it takes care of finding the right values):

```
temp = df.stack()
zipped = [*zip(index, columns)]
temp.loc(axis=0)[zipped].array
<PandasArray>
[4, 2]
Length: 2, dtype: int64
```